# How to auto-generate Magento URL Rewrites?

Tags: magento

I've adapted the Ebizmarts Customerprofile module for a project I'm working on and I need to automatically rewrite any requests to:

```
mymagestore.com/profile/USERNAME
```

to

```
mymagestore.com/customerprofile/account/view/username/USERNAME
```

Sounds simple enough but these are the options I'm considering.  Has anyone done this in the past, if so, how did you accomplish it?

1. .htaccess RewriteRule (con: outside of Magento)
2. Custom Magento index process to create Magento URL Rewrites (pro: within Magento and would be good time for some other cleanup, con: more work)
3. Observe when Customer object is saved and create URL Rewrite then (pro: within Magento, con: could leave orphaned rows and probably not upgrade-proof)

Thanks for your time,
Wilson

Comment: #1 - being 'outside of Magento' is not a con. This is the easiest solution. I'd suggest using it.

Answer (score 0):

Good point Zachary.  For anyone who's looking, the only way, I found, to do a custom Magento RewriteRule is to use mod_proxy with the the P flag.

I.e.

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /customerprofile/account/view/username/$1 [P]
```

Details:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p